# How do I set an EKEvent to recur variable days prior to a specific date?

Tags: cocoa, ekeventkit

**Background Info**

I have a class that contains an `NSDate` object that is used as the date of an `EKEvent`.  The `EKEvent` is added to the Calendar, sometimes with an `EKRecurrenceRule` set, with a date that is x amount of days prior to the actual date of the event.  For example, if dateOfEvent is 02/01/2013 and the user elects to be alerted 2 days prior, the event will be added to the Calendar on 01/30/2013.

Here is how I am getting the prior date:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = ([daysPrior integerValue] * -1);
NSDate *alertDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components
                                                                  toDate:[myClass dateOfEvent]
                                                                 options:0];
```

**Current Issue**

When setting the `EKRecurrenceRule` to `EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly` it selects the day of the month from alertDate in each month.  With the example above that day ends up being the 30th, however February does not have a 30th day and the event never gets added to February.  How can I make it actually set the days prior in each month rather than basing it off a specific number?

**Failed Attempts**

I tried adding negative days to the recurrence rule hoping it would base it off of the event date I set and move backward but instead it added the event to every day on the calendar.

```
NSMutableArray *daysOfMonth = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int x;
for (x = 0; x > -31; x--) {
    [daysOfMonth addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
}
EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly
                                                                      interval:1
                                                                 daysOfTheWeek:nil
                                                                daysOfTheMonth:daysOfMonth
                                                               monthsOfTheYear:nil
                                                                weeksOfTheYear:nil
                                                                 daysOfTheYear:nil
                                                                  setPositions:nil
                                                                           end:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use an `EKAlarm` and added it to each event.

```
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60 * 60 * 24 * ([daysPrior integerValue] * -1)];
[newEvent addAlarm:alarm];
```

This way I can add the date of the event on the calendar at its actual date and still alert the user x amount of days prior.